# laravel 5.1 OR in if statement not working

Tags: php, if-statement, laravel-5.1

Okay,

simple IF statement, simple code, can't find the solution for some reason

```
if (substr(Auth::User()->email, -14) != "@thomasmore.be" || substr(Auth::User()->email, -22) != "@student.thomasmore.be")
    {
        echo substr(Auth::User()->email, -14);
    }
```

echoes:

> @thomasmore.be

when I just use:

```
if(substr(Auth::User()->email, -14) != "@thomasmore.be")
```

it works perfectly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `||` -> `&&`. You want that it can't be `@thomasmore.be` AND `@thomasmore.be` ; Right now you have: Something else than `@thomasmore.be` OR `@thomasmore.be`

Comment: @Rizier123 yup that was it. Something so simple and I looked over it. I apologize, thanks for the help!

Comment: Sometimes writing down logic in plain English can help to understand it and find the error.